# Расположение компонентов поверх друг друга (по оси z)

Tags: android, android-studio, cardview, android-linearlayout, scrollview

Нужно два градиентных прямоугольника расположить поверх белого прямоугольника.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_fgmt_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back_picture_content_fragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Budget"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_money_block_1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Zatrati_Ostalos"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_money_block_2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Zatrati"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Ostalos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_transparent_fragment_content"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LayoutOfScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть сказали, какой элемент как в коде называется. А вообще попробуйте FrameLayout.

Comment: Разметка уж совсем тривиальная, я думал очевидно. Две CardView - два градиентных прямоугольника. ScrollView - белый прямоугольник

Comment: Перенесите скроллвью в структуре перед двумя прямоугольниками.

Comment: Эникейщик, эмм...так просто) Кажется, все выглядит как нужно). При много благодарен)

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

`CoordinatorLayout` используемый в разметке это прокачанный `FrameLayout`. А одной из основных особенностей `FrameLayout` является способ расположения элементов на экране - они накладываются друг на друга как в фоторамке (photo frame), в которую помещают несколько картинок (отсюда и название для такой разметки - **Frame**Layout). Те элементы, которые в xml определены позже, накладываются на те, которые определены раньше. Поэтому для того, чтобы какой-нибудь элемент расположить поверх всего, его нужно поместить в самый конец xml. Соответственно, тот элемент, который должен быть позади всех, должен быть в начале xml.

Возвращаясь к прямоугольникам: оба `CardView` (зеленый и фиолетовый прямоугольник) расположены в xml раньше, чем `ScrollView` (белый прямоугольник). Поэтому белый прямоугольник появляется на экране позже и, соответственно, поверх двух других. Поменяв их местами в xml, мы получим нужный эффект (для компактности убрал парметры и пустые строки):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Scroll">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LayoutOfScroll">
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Budget">
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Zatrati_Ostalos">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Zatrati">
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Ostalos"
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Пояснение внесло полную ясность) Спасибо Вам большое)